# Cannot properly display unicode string after parsing a file with lxml, works fine with simple file read

Tags: python, lxml

I'm attempting to use the lxml module to parse HTML files, but am struggling to get it to work with some UTF-8 encoded data. I'm using Python 2.7 on Windows. For example, consider a UTF-8 encoded file without byte order mark that contains nothing but the text string `Québec`. If I just read the contents of the file using a regular file handler and decode the resulting string object, I get a length 6 unicode string that looks good when written back to a file. But if I parse the file with lxml, I see get a length 7 unicode string that looks odd when written back to a file. Can someone explain what is happening differently with lxml and how to get the original, pretty string?

For example:

```
import lxml.html as html
from lxml import etree

f = open("output.txt", "w")

text = open("input.txt").read().decode("utf-8")
f.write("String of type '%s' with length %d: %s\n" % (type(text), len(text), text.encode("utf-8")))

root = html.parse("input.txt")
text = root.xpath(".//p")[0].text.strip()
f.write("String of type '%s' with length %d: %s\n" % (type(text), len(text), text.encode("utf-8")))
```

Produces output in `output.txt` of:

```
String of type '<type 'unicode'>' with length 6: Québec
String of type '<type 'unicode'>' with length 7: QuÃ©bec
```

**EDIT**

A partial workaround here seems to be to parse the file using:

```
etree.parse("input.txt", etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))
```

or

```
html.parse("input.txt", etree.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))
```

However, as far as I know the base etree library lacks some convenience classes for things like selectors, so a solution that allows me to use lxml.html without etree.HTMLParser() would still be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function `lxml.html.parse` **already** uses an instance of lxml.html.HTMLParser, so you shouldn't really be averse to using

```
html.parse("input.txt", html.HTMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))
```

to handle the utf-8 data

Comment: the issue (admittedly a small one) is that when HTMLParser() is used it doesn't look like I can use the HTML Element Methods listed on http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html. Not that big a deal since I can always use pure xpath workarounds, but sometimes they can look a little cleaner.

Comment: I'd expect you **can**.  In the code above we're creating a `lxml.html.HTMLParser`, not a `lxml.etree.HTMLParser` ... and the former should return augmented node objects.  A call to `html.parse(txt)` is really `html.parse(txt, html.HTMLParser())` ... so here we're just helping it out a bit.