# everything is utf-8 .. but I only get dirt

Tags: python, encoding, lxml

I want to get the name for a phone number calling me and this is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import lxml.html

telnr="0306636793"
root=lxml.html.parse("http://www.11880.com/rueckwaertssuche/%s"%telnr).getroot()
h3=root.cssselect('h3')
print h3[0].text_content()
```

It works great, if there are no "special characters" (like german "Umlaute") in the result.

But if ...for example... "Müller, Egon" is calling me, I get "MÃ¼ller, Egon".

What do I have to do, to get the result with the right encoding?

Comment: It may be that the result does have the right encoding, but wherever you're printing it (e.g., the terminal) doesn't.

Comment: No. I put it the code in a wxpython-programm and added the name as developer: d=h3[0].text_content()  info.AddDeveloper(d) and the dialog also shows "MÃ¼ller, Egon".

Comment: a   print h3[0].text_content().encode("ISO 8859-1")   did the trick also....but I do not understand, why...!?

Comment: Apparently because `lxml.html` is not that great at handling encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this page](http://raj.blog.archive.org/2012/07/19/parsing-utf-8-webpages-with-lxml/) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9284480/cannot-properly-display-unicode-string-after-parsing-a-file-with-lxml-works-fin), `lxml.html.parse` doesn't handle page encodings properly.  You need to do it like this:

```
import lxml.html

telnr = "0306636793"
p = lxml.html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8')
root = lxml.etree.parse("http://www.11880.com/rueckwaertssuche/%s"%telnr, parser=p).getroot()
h3 = root.cssselect(b'h3')
txt = h3[0].text_content()
```

Comment: I only get an AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'cssselect' !?

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete code snippet.  It works for me.  Are you sure you're using the same code?

Comment: I tried it with lxml.html.parse. It works great with lxml.etree.parse :-) ...and without the need to install python-bs4, which is not in my standard-opensuse-repos.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's going on with `lxml`, but I was able to come up with a workaround using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

telnr = "0306636793"
r = requests.get("http://www.11880.com/rueckwaertssuche/%s" % telnr)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
name = soup.find_all('h3')[0].text
print(name)
```

Running this gives:

```
$ python telnr.py
Müller, Egon
```